# Get a stored procedure from other user in Oracle using Dreamfactory

Tags: php, oracle, api

I'm using [DreamFactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com/) to access an Oracle Database, I get tables with no problem, but when I tried to access procedures or functions, I can only get access to the same user, how can I call a stored procedure saved in another user?

Comment: have you granted execute on the procedure/function to the user from the database?

Comment: @kevinsky, well I'm not the DB Analyst, it looks like there's some broken packages, he told me he would be working on this, as soon as this is solved I'll make some tests again, thanks.

Comment: Packages that will not compile would give you an error message.  This sounds like a permissions/roles issue.  You should be able to look at the privileges for the user and see/or not see  Grant execute on Schema.Package To User

Answer (score 1):

DreamFactory should obey your db's permissions. If you list procedures (do a GET on {service name}/_proc
That will list all procedures your account has access to.
Consult with your dba for gaining access to other procedures.
Than you can do a GET on {service name}/_proc?refresh=true to update the list of available procedures.